# I am writing a telegram bot on Google app script, the array data is automatically reset, can I not save the user data to the array?

Tags: google-apps-script, telegram-bot

```
var user_data2=[];

function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

        if (contents.message) {
          var chatId = contents.message.chat.id;
            if (contents.message.text == '/start') {
              sendKey(chatId, ' Add user', keyB_user_add);
            } else if (contents.message.text && user_data2.length == 0){
              send_text(chatId, 'Familiyani tuboring:');
              user_data2.push(contents.message.text);
              send_text(chatId, user_data2);
            } else if (contents.message.text && user_data2.length == 1){
              send_text(chatId, 'Ismni yuboring:');
              user_data2.push(contents.message.text);
              send_text(chatId, user_data2);
            } 

        }  else
```

Comment: I am writing a telegram bot on Google app script, there, after the array is declared, after each content update, the array data is automatically reset, can not I save the user data to the array?

Answer (score 1):

### You can use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service)

In Apps Script, variable contents are not being stored between two script runs - even if they are global variables

`PropertiesService` allows you to store data in a cache between and retrieve whenever you need it.

Sample:

```
function doPost(e) {
  if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){ // first time you run the script
    PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('user_data2', "");
    return;
  }
  var user_data2 = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('user_data2');
  // do whatever you want  
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('user_data2', user_data2);
}
```

Basically, the first time you run the function, you initialize the script property. It will keep whatever value you assign to it with `setProperty`. Next time, when you run the function - you can retrieved the stored value with `getProperty`.